# unexpected indent error occur in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to python. I developed test case using selenium webdriver in python language. And this is my code.

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver =webdriver.Firefox()

def test(self):
    driver=self.driver
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Providers").click()
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Userid")))
     elt=driver.find_element_by_id("Userid")

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()
```

While running the program i got the error as

```
File "testcase.py", line 21
    elt=driver.find_element_by_id("Userid")
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I cant find the error in it. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: There is an extra space before `elt=...`

Comment: There is an extra space before `elt`?

Comment: This appears to be off-topic because it is about correcting a typo. I wonder who would upvote such a question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, the code blocks are defined by their indentation.

Any extra indentation out of place (i.e., without `if`, `while` and other such constructs) will throw an `IndentationError`. Thus, within the same block of code, you must maintain the same amount of indentation. You can further refer [this](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html).

In your current code, you have an extra space before `elt` and that is throwing up the error.

Comment: thank you after grouping the statements its work for me